# Collapsing repeating rows of dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have dataframe `df` which looks as following:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    StartDate   EndDate     Qty
24HR    A1      B1      1/1/2020    1/31/2020   4.2
24HR    A1      B1      2/1/2020    2/29/2020   11
asd     A2      B2      2/1/2020    2/29/2020   35
asd     A2      B2      3/1/2020    3/31/2020   23
asd     A2      B2      4/1/2020    4/30/2020   35
asd     A2      B2      5/1/2020    5/31/2020   46
```

I need to collapse the rows based on repeats in `Col1, Col2, Col3` to get the following:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    StartDate   EndDate     Jan  Feb    Mar  Apr    May
24HR    A1      B1      1/1/2020    2/29/2020   4.2  11         
asd     A2      B2      2/1/2020    5/31/2020        35     23    35    46
```

The `StartDate` and `EndDate` for above is the min and max for all columns. i.e. for columns with values `24HR, A1, B1`, the min `StartDate` is `1/1/2020` and max `EndDate` is `2/29/2020`.

I tried the following:

```
df['MnthName'] = df['StartDate'].dt.strftime('%b')
df = df.pivot_table(index=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'], values='Qty', columns='MnthName')
```

But I am not sure how to group it to select min of `StartDate` and max of `EndDate` for each of `Col1, Col2, Col3` unique pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `pivot` and `agg` then `concat` them together

```
s1=df.pivot_table(index=['Col1','Col2','Col3'],columns='StartDate',values='Qty')

s2=df.groupby(['Col1','Col2','Col3']).agg({'StartDate':'first','EndDate':'last'})
s1.columns=pd.to_datetime(s1.columns,dayfirst=False).strftime('%b')
s=pd.concat([s2,s1],axis=1).reset_index()
s
   Col1 Col2 Col3 StartDate    EndDate  Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May
0  24HR   A1   B1  1/1/2020  2/28/2020  4.2  11.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   asd   A2   B2  2/1/2020  5/31/2020  NaN  35.0  23.0  35.0  46.0
```